# Reload View everytime its presented (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, xcode11

how can i reset a view when its dismissed ?

If i dismiss the view and present it again for example with a button it's at it's state it was before the dismiss which i don't want. I want that the view will be presented at its original first state everytime i push the button that presents the view.

here is how i present the view:

```swift
Button(action: {
   self.showPicker = true
}) {
   Image(systemName: "photo")
        .font(.title)
}.sheet(isPresented: self.$showPicker) {
   ImagePickerController(selectedImage: self.$pickedImage, sourceType: .photoLibrary)
}
```

Before and after the dismiss:

[image]

Comment: You need to show more code - basically, reset the state and the view will follow. More specifically (and here's where more code would help), are you simply trying to reset `$pickedImage`, something more, and who is the owner of the state you are trying to reset. As it is, you have't given us enough to duplicate the issue you are facing.

Comment: @dfd You haven't understood my issue. I have a button that presents a next screen. On the next screen i can browse in it how i want. At the end i dismiss that screen with swiping it down. If i present that screen again with the button i get that screen at the exact same state it was before and its not at its first state even tho `ImagePickerController` initializer was called which should make a brand new view